# html after the_content () wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to add an icon after "the_content". Below works with the_title(), but it doesn't work with the_content(). Anyone know how I could accomplish this?

```
<blockquote><?php the_content('', '<i class="fa fa-quote-right"></i>'); ?> <--- This is what I'm trying to figure out.
     <cite>&mdash; <?php the_title(); ?></cite>
</blockquote>
```

So if I were to try the_title('', 'html_code') it would append the desired html. Essentially, I want to append html to "the_content()" the same way I can with "the_title()". I hope that clarifies it.

Comment: I think this is very vague. What do you mean by it doesn't work?

Comment: @user8262086 I hope I clarified it enough. Sorry about that.

Comment: the_content() and the_title() do not have the same parameters, in particular the second parameter to the_content() is a boolean not a string. You cannot use the_content() to get the result you want. Why can't you just put the icon code before your cite element?

Comment: @user8262086 I tried that, but it gives me an undesired effect. It puts everything in a paragraph and pushes the icon down.

Comment: So, actually you don't want to append but actually embed in the content somewhere near the end. Then I think the_content() is too late as it is just outputting already formed stuff. I think you should consider the filter 'content_pagination' which is done earlier.

Comment: I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try to escape the double-quotes in there:

```
<?php the_content('', '<i class=\"fa fa-quote-right\"></i>'); ?>
```